# NoSuchPathException in the bitbucket github api

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

We are using Bitbucket github and I am using their API to update an file like below

https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.7.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45568365784624

In case of updating the README.md, it works as expected

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password -F content=@README.md  -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API'
 -F branch=master -F  sourceCommitId=5636641a50b
  http://example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/PROJECT_1/repos/repo_1/browse/test/README.md
```

Updating the file in github repo works as expected but when I try to create the new file path like below

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password -F content=@README.md  -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API'
     -F branch=master -F  sourceCommitId=5636641a50b
      http://example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/PROJECT_1/repos/repo_1/browse/test/newfile.md
```

it fails with the error : **NoSuchPathException**

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "context": null,
            "message": "test/newfile.md could not be edited because the file has been deleted on the 4186264533e065bd10ad2baf307f5687afcb445c branch.",
            "exceptionName": "com.atlassian.bitbucket.content.NoSuchPathException"
        }
    ]
}
```

As per the documentation, It says both the update and create should work as expected but only UPDATE is working and CREATING A NEW FILE fails

**branch: the branch on which the path should be modified or created**

Anyhelp on this is appreciated!

Comment: Bitbucket is not GitHub; the Bitbucket API is not the GitHub API; neither of these is Git itself. Bitbucket and GItHub are *hosting sites* (with different APIs). I updated your tags, but when you mean Bitbucket, just say Bitbucket, not "Bitbucket GitHub".

Answer (score 0):

For people running into this issue, you need to remove the `sourceCommitId` parameter for new files. Seems like the `sourceCommitId` is needed only for existing files.

That would be something like:

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password -F content=@README.md  -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API'
     -F branch=master -F
      http://example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/PROJECT_1/repos/repo_1/browse/test/newfile.md
```